# Split string from file

Tags: vb.net, file, file-io

I have a file in which the name of a book and its author is on each line. (EX: "Douglas Adams,The Hitchhiker's Guide To The Galaxy" is one line of the file). I can read each line into a temporary string, but when I split it at the comma to put the author and book in different arrays, it won't work.

Here is my code:

```
objReader = New StreamReader(AppPath() + "books\books.txt")
i = 1
Dim temp() As String
Dim tempStr As String
Do While objReader.Peek() <> -1
  tempStr = objReader.ReadLine()
  temp = tempStr.Split(New Char() {","c})
  temp(0) = authors(i)
  temp(1) = books(i)
  i = i + 1
Loop
```

I already initialized objReader and i earlier, and I imported System.IO, too.
I have tried to change the delimiters to semicolons, slashes, and backslashes in both the code and the file, but it doesn't work. I can confirm the file loads correctly.

Comment: In what way doesn't it work?  Are you sure that `temp(0) = authors(i)` is the right way around?  It looks as though you might mean `authors(i) = temp(0)` instead.  (And the same for `books(i)`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to put the string in the arrays, you're doing it the other way around:

```
authors(i) = temp(0)
books(i) = temp(1)
```